# Inverse of Score and Covariance/Variance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I need to proof the following:

$(A'A + B^{-1})^{-1}A' = BA'(ABA' + I)^{-1}$

Where B $\in{R}^{k \times k}$ is a variance matrix, $A\in R^{n \times k}$ of full rank. Unfortunately, I seem to get stuck. Could anyone offer a helping hand?

Comment: are you sure of your formula ? (If we agree that $A'$ designates the transpose of $A$) I have tried on examples and I don't find the same result in the LHS and the RHS... but may be I am wrong...

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure. The left-hand side is my derivation of the posterior mean of a linear model, whereas the right-hand side is the model given by the book. I think: https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/32750/BU-647-M.version2.pdf;jsessionid=2CD5B8D3BE174436BB512CAFC4459289?sequence=1 (page 4), has some reference. I also sampled some random matrices and found that RHS and LHS are equal.

Comment: Well, happy that you have discovered the little problem...

Comment: It seemed I messed up ABA instead of BAB. Fixed it now:-)

Comment: As you seem a newcomer in stackoverflow, the usage is that, when a solution agrees to the asker, he/she checks it in the margin (you can see these green check signs on the left of all former questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $$(A'A + B^{-1})^{-1}A' = BA'(ABA' + I)^{-1}$$

right-multiplying both sides by $(ABA' + I)$ and left-multiplying both sides by $(A'A + B^{-1})$, one obtains the equivalent statement:

$$A'(ABA' + I)=(A'A + B^{-1})BA'$$

which is evident by development.